# Algorithm to create a dynamic range system?

Tags: python, algorithm, automation, range

I have a data set of 150 users, each user has a value and these values are placed in a LOG range lets say 0-300, each value in the range is then mapped to a score value from 0-100. as the number of users increases their values might also increase. lets say there are now 300 users and the value ranges from 0-1000 now. How could i create an algorithm in python or another language that automatically changes the range an the corresponding score (0-100) for the values in the range.

Comment: Provide a comprehensive example, please, in order to get further assistance.

Comment: What is your code so far? Have you even tried some methods on implementing this problem?

Comment: Well Mongey, i have a simple equation which updates a value in the old range into the new range. X= original value. Range (0-300)
Y=new value. Range (0-1000)
A1-A2 = old range
B1-B2 = new range
Y= ((x-a1)/ (a2-a1))*(b2-b1) +b1
I need a system which updates the range when data increases and also updates the score distribution which the values in the range correspond to. As far as code goes I have not accomplished much as I am a bit of a n00b. any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: So are you asking for something an algorithm to determine what the new range should be?

Comment: OK so, lets say a user has a value of 100 (range 0-300) which equates to a score of 40 in the old range what I need to know is how to distribute the score (0-100) when the values in the range are updating and changing and how to automate the updating of the range and the updating of the corresponding scores as new data is coming in? get me?

Comment: You are trying to normalize input data to a score of 0-100?

Comment: well yes i am assigning a score (0-100) to each user based on some user data. But i am not sure of how to automate the change in the distribution of each range ( the range of data and the score range)

Comment: I still don't get it. Could you create an example of the data input and desired data output?

Comment: e.g. : 150 users, each user has a value for frequency of blog posts these range from 0-300 a LOG range from 0-300 is created. each value of frequency has a corresponding score. e.g frequency of 100 equates to a score of 40. As the number of users increases the frequency values will increase and differ--- so now say the range of frequency increases to 0-1000 while the score range stays at 0-100. I am trying to construct an algorithm which updates the distributions of both the frequency values in the range and the score distribution as the amount of data increases and increases.

Comment: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s318/sh/69f42250-9d73-40ff-83f9-8408088b6675/cb6bceb6f69af2bd91b603ea60c48212

Comment: You should keep your data unnormalized as long as possible. Each new datapoint could change the range, right? So, keep track of the maximum value while adding data points. As soon as you need the score, you can easily compute it using score = point * 100 / MAX(POINTS)

Comment: yes true the range will need to be altered with new data points. However, I am looking for an algorithm that will automatically update the normalized scale and how it is distributed and how the score scale is distributed and matched to each value range